# Interpret the arrows in a circuit diagram of an OP-amp

Tags: operational-amplifier, circuit-analysis, diagram

I have the following diagram of an ideal OP and 
$$
y=-Ae \tag 1
$$

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f9zSM7.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I'm not used of using arrows for voltages, so I don't grasp the meaning of the arrow \$e\$. I tried to redraw the diagram below. Is \$e\$ the voltage difference between the inputs \$+\$ and \$- \$? I call them \$v_2\$ and \$v_1\$ below, so is \$e=v_2-v_1\$?.

Is the following diagram equal to the one above?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fjJDXN.png)</sup>

And also, why the negative sign in equation \$(1)\$? 
Using my diagram we have \$e=v_2-v_1\$ and \$v_2=0\$ so
\$
y=Ae=A(v_2-v_1)=-Av_1.
\$
But this is not equal to equation \$(1)\$...

Comment: A voltage is the difference between two point. An arrow is not unusual to make clear which two points. The convention is that the point of the arrow has a higher potential then the tail. Some times the voltage polarity is unknown. Then you just choose an arbitrary arrow direction. If your subsequent calculations produce a negative voltage this means that the original guessed arrow direction was wrong.

Answer (score 1):

The arrow simply define the voltage direction notation. It's really super easy:

```
-------------->

|            |
attach     attach
voltmeter  voltmeter
"-" here   "+" here
```

As you can see, that's necessary – it's not inherently clear which way around you'd measure voltage, and if you have an equation like \$y=-Ae\$, it'd be ambiguous.

Having that arrow is also a necessity, because what you do, introducing a ground potential at the positive input of the opamp, can't always be done – *absolute voltages don't exist – everything is potential relative to an arbitrarily chosen point*. And the arrow does nothing but define "the voltage I measure here is between the potential at the start of my arrow, and its tip – so subtract the start potential from the tip potential to get the voltage".

Comment: Note that this can be different across different languages/cultures; I know I've read that the arrow points towards the negative end in some European engineering traditions. (which causes some Annoyances when trying to use CircuiTikZ...)

Answer (score 1):

I think you're **overthinking** the difference between using arrows (upper schematic) and the more common + / - signs and ground symbols (lower schematic). Basically they're different ways of indicating the same thing, a voltage and it's polarity.

**However** in the upper schematic with the arrows, it is **undefined** what connects to "ground level potential. All voltages are **referenced** to the line connecting to the + input of the opamp but nothing says that the voltage on that line is the ground reference. In the bottom schematic that is indicated clearly with the ground symbols.

The "e" in the bottom schematic is confusing and it is not following conventions, it has no + and - so I cannot see what "e" means.

Yes the circuits are the same.

To "easily" understand that there must be a minus sign in the transfer, you must realize that the opamp will steer it's output such that the voltage difference between its (+ and -) inputs is **zero**. That means that the opamp **forces** the voltage at the - input to be **zero** (because the + input connects to ground so it is zero volt by definition).

Knowing that, now work put what the output will be when the input has a positive voltage. Z1 and Z2 work as a voltage divider so the voltage at the output of the opamp must become negative to satisfy the zero volt at the - input.

Learn more by reading [Opamps for Everyone](https://web.mit.edu/6.101/www/reference/op_amps_everyone.pdf).

Comment: If the arrow "indicates the voltage and it's polarity", then why do the arrows representing "u" and "y" have the same direction although the voltages have opposite polarities? What is the point then of the arrows having a direction if all they point up? Isn't it better if they have two tops? Or they to have no peak at all (to be just sections)? Then they will only indicate the two points between which the voltage is. It turns out this is the only benefit of these arrows...

Comment: @Circuitfantasist *then why do the arrows representing "u" and "y" have the same direction although the voltages have opposite polarities?* You are thinking that the arrow should also indicate the **actual value** of that voltage. That isn't the intention and also isn't needed! The direction of the arrow is a **choice**. Often this choice is made in a simple way: all arrows point upwards. Then only **after** analyzing the circuit it becomes obvious that the voltage y is negative if the voltage u is positive. But also, if u was negative then y would be positive!

Comment: That an arrow points upwards or that a net is marked "+" doesn't mean that the voltage cannot be **negative**. They're unrelated!

Comment: Bimpelrekkie, I see... but this technique is formal and suitable only for the purposes of calculation. When inventing, understanding and explaining circuits in an intuitive manner, we need (when possible) to know the actual voltage polarities and current directions... and some approximate values ​​and relations between them. That is why, I depict voltages by segments with
proportional height (voltage bars) and currents by closed paths (loops) with proportional thickness. They represent the current state of the quantities (something like a snapshot).

Comment: @Circuitfantasist Those arrows, as well as the equivalent +/- symbols, express the ***reference direction*** of voltages, not actual polarity. It's like a frame of reference in mechanics. Once you set the reference, then you can write equations using the voltage symbols. Without that reference *choice* (as Bimplerekkie said), you can't write equations or formulas. Assuming the references express the real polarity is naive. Put an AC signal there and the point of "actual polarity" is moot. What matters is the relations (equations) between quantities, and these need references.

Comment: @Circuitfantasist Even Ohms law is NOT \$V=R\cdot I\$, but \$V=-R \cdot I\$ if you choose the reference directions of V and I using the so called "generator convention", instead of the more usual "load convention".

Answer (score 1):

Gnd is simply a reference to be considered as 0V.

The start of an arrow is similar as a 0V reference to show the difference at the tip.

In this case they are both 0V.

We call the Op Amp differential input as a “virtual ground” to mean any voltage within spec that are equal.   But as the equation shows, it’s not exactly 0V difference but for A = 1e6 if the input is 1V and the R values are equal, Vout must go to -1 V to make Vin- = Vin+=0V=gnd. But actually that voltage is 1V/1e6 or 1uV which may be nice to know, but for practical purposes we call it “virtually the same voltage a Vin+= 0V

So e = V1 = “Vin-“

So 0V ground is a low impedance point and e is low impedance near 0V  but current limited by Z2 for linear operation.